# Running a check on content loaded in via a .load() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

had this niggling issue that i cant seem to figure out.

I have a blog post on a CMS that i am building and there is some content saved into a div with it own unique ID. When the user clicks an edit button, a CKeditor is shown (containing the same text as the div). I also display a save button which when clicked, calls the processing PHP script via AJAX.

On a database update success, i use this in my AJAX call:

```
if (response.databaseSuccess) {
  $("#container #" +response.postid).load("#container #" +response.postContentID);
}
```

This works perfectly and loads the updated content into the div.

Now the issue...

On page load i use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // check each image in the .blogtest divs for their width. If its less than X make it full size, if not its poor and keep it normal
    function resize() {
    var box = $(".blogtest");
    box.find("img.buildimage").on('load', function () {
        var img = $(this),
            width = img.width();
        if (width >= 650) {
            img.addClass("buildimage-large");
        } else if (width < 500 && width > 101) {
            img.addClass("buildimage-small");
        }
        // if image is less than X, its most likely a smiley
        else if (width < 100) {
            img.addClass("buildimage-smiley");
        }
        }).filter(function () {
            //if the image is already loaded manually trigger the event
            return this.complete;
        }).trigger('load');
    }
    resize();
});
```

This works, and checks the images for their width and acts accordingly. After the page has fully loaded the images correctly get given their new class which changes their width.

The problem is that i cannot get this function to work on the data that is saved. So when i click save and the content is loaded via .load(), the new images are not checked.

I have tried adding the above function into the AJAX success return but it doesnt do anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to hook into the `onload` event for images that have already been added to the page, it is very easy to miss the `onload` event, particularly if the image is already in the browser cache (and thus will load quickly) as the `onload` event may have already fired before you get a chance to attach your event handler.  The usual work-around is to do something like this where you check to see if it's already loaded before attaching an `onload` handler:

```
box.find("img.buildimage").each(function() {
    if (this.complete) {
        // image already loaded so just process it here
    } else {
        // image not yet loaded so attach an onload handler
        $(this).on("load", function() {
            // now the image is loaded so process it here
        });
    } 
});
```

---

I'm not sure exactly what code you're using to dynamically load new content.  If you're doing that with Ajax, you need to make sure you don't fire the above code until after the content has been added to the page (the success or completion handler of whatever load operation you're using).

So, if this is where you're loading new content:

```
if (response.databaseSuccess) {
  $("#container #" +response.postid).load("#container #" +response.postContentID);
}
```

then, you would use a completion handler callback on the `.load()` function to trigger the above code:

```
if (response.databaseSuccess) {
  $("#container #" +response.postid).load("#container #" +response.postContentID, function() {
      // code here that looks at the dynamically loaded content
  });
}
```

Comment: Simple as that! Keep forgetting javascript doesn't work like PHP! Thanks shall keep a note of this in the future.